# how do I create a python list with a negative index

Tags: python, list, indexing

I'm new to python and need to create a list with a negative index but have not been successful so far.

I'm using this code:

```
a = []
for i in xrange( -20, 0, -1 ):
    a[i] = -(i)
    log.info('a[{i}]={v}'.format(i=i, v=a[i]))
else:
    log.info('end')
```

and getting the log output as

```
end
```

Incidentally I'm using a site call quantopian so the log.info is from their infrastructure and just print out the output into a web console.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What do you want the output to be?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Quantopian, it is advisable that you become familiar with numpy and pandas. For example:

```
>>> import numpy as np 
>>> -1*np.arange(20)

array([  0,  -1,  -2,  -3,  -4,  -5,  -6,  -7,  -8,  -9, -10, -11, -12,
       -13, -14, -15, -16, -17, -18, -19])
```

Then you will have `a[1]==-1`, `a[5]==-5`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I know numpy and pandas play a lot on this site but have avoided it mostly up to know. I will take a closer look though. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

the only thing that strikes me is

```
 for i in xrange( -20, 0, -1 ):
```

seems very wrong since the third argument is step size... you will go -1 per step starting at -20, means next number is -21

and the following is a syntax error

```
a = []
a[0] = 5
```

you should do `a = [None]*20`

Answer (score 2):

Negative indices correlate with some positive counterpart, so a list will not help.
If you want to hold data at negative and positive positions, use a dict:

**Given**

```
numline = range(-3, 3)
data = "abcedfg"
```

**Code**

```
a = dict(zip(numline, data))
a
# {-3: 'a', -2: 'b', -1: 'c', 0: 'e', 1: 'd', 2: 'f'}

a[-1]
# 'c'
```

Here we make sure the keys of the dict are a number line spanning the range we desire.  Index it as you would a regular list, except now the negative indices are independent.  However, slicing does not work like a list.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
xrange( -20, 0, -1 )
```

Is trying to go from -20 to 0 (exclusive) backwards (i.e. via -21, -22, etc.) Since that's going in the 'wrong' direction, iteration is going to stop immediately without yielding any elements. [This page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) gives you a more technical explanation of that (although its for `range`, which is somewhat similar):

> [...] if step is negative, the last element is the smallest start + i
>   * step greater than stop.

Additionally, you are attempting to write to a list at indices of it that don't already exist (never mind the fact that you want them to be negative - negative indices have a special meaning in Python) - this would be a problem if execution ever entered the body of the loop. Lists don't work like associative arrays - you can't set values for arbitrary keys.

If you can tell us what output you are expecting, we can help you fix both of these problems.

Comment: Hi, Ok so if negative indices in python read backwards then I should be able to do for i in xrange(20): a[i]=i and then afterwards do a a[-4] to read the 5th element from the end! Is this correct? Thanks for you answer.

Comment: Yes, but you'd have to do `a.append(i)` instead of `a[i]=i`. Also, `a[-4]` provides the 4th element from the end, not the 5th. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a list with negative indices. They start with zero and count up by 1. If you use a negative index when accessing an element, Python converts that to a positive index relative to the end of the list.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a[0]
1
>>> a[2]
3
>>> a[-1]   # Same as a[len(a)-1]
3
```

If you need negative indices, you'll have to use a dict, which supports arbitrary (hashable) keys.