# What is [index-1] doing in the answer? in plain English

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

First of all, I am a Python newbie.

Second, this is actually an Exercism exercise.

Thirdly, I am totally new to matrixes, but I have learnt quite a lot in the last two weeks.

Fourthly, I am totally new to the concept of Classes, still trying to wrap my mind around those. But that is not in issue here.

Finally, I stumbled upon the following question, and the answer stupifies me.

**Where I need clarification**

1. What is [index-1] doing in the answer?

**What I have done so far**

I have gone through lots of tutorials on arrays and matrixs in python but I haven't found one that helped me understand how [index-1] in this answer works. I do understand the concept of 2D arrays and matrixs in Python though.

**The Question**

Given a string representing a matrix of numbers, return the rows and columns of that matrix.

So given a string with embedded newlines like:

```
9 8 7
5 3 2
6 6 7
```

representing this matrix:

```
    1  2  3
  |---------
1 | 9  8  7
2 | 5  3  2
3 | 6  6  7
```

your code should be able to spit out:

A list of the rows, reading each row left-to-right while moving top-to-bottom across the rows,

A list of the columns, reading each column top-to-bottom while moving from left-to-right.

The rows for our example matrix:

```
9, 8, 7
5, 3, 2
6, 6, 7
```

And its columns:

```
9, 5, 6
8, 3, 6
7, 2, 7
```

**Answer:**

```
class Matrix:

     def __init__(self, matrix_string):

        self.matrix = [row.split(' ') for row in matrix_string.splitlines()]
        

def row(self, index):
        return self.matrix[index-1]

def column(self, index):
        return [row[index-1] for row in self.matrix]
```

Comment: Are you aware that list indices start with `0`, not `1`?

Comment: Index are the position of the each element.

Comment: @chepner I am aware.

Comment: @ch2019 That much I know. I know that an index can be positive and negative

Comment: @ElectronicsNewbie that's not true. An index cannot be negative. 0 is it's lowest value.

Comment: @zoharcochavi I see. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27431374/how-do-i-create-a-python-list-with-a-negative-index#:~:text=You%20can't%20create%20a%20list%20with%20negative%20indices.,a[-1]%20#%20Same%20as%20a%20[len%20(a)-1]%203 agrees with you!

Comment: @zoharcochavi Not entirely true. Negative indices are treated as offsets from the end of the list, rather than offsets from the beginning. For that reason, one has to take care when  computing indices; just as adding can result in an `IndexError`, so too can subtracting produce a more subtle semantic error. (More generally, the index can be anything that the type's `__getitem__` method is willing to accept. The semantics of integer indices, whether positive or negative, are defined by `list.__getitem__`.)

Comment: @chepner You are totally right! That is my mistake!

Comment: @chepner Your input has been invaluable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists (or arrays as they're often called in other languages) in programming start from index 0. If I have a list of elements say `[a, b, c ,d ,e]`, then index `0` would correspond to character `a`. Index `1` to character `b` and so on.

The index in a matrix (in this case) starts counting from `1`. Thus, when you say: "I want the element from index `1`", the computer would throw you the *second* element. To compensate for this, we subtract `1`. That way, when you ask for the element at index `1`, the computer will actually read the value at index `1-1`, so `0`.

Comment: So index -1 is the same thing as index-0?

Comment: @ElectronicsNewbie Well, no, you subtract something from it, it won't be the same. The most important this to get from this is that the first element of your matrix is at index 1, and the first element of a list in python is at 0. Thus, you have to subtract 1 from the 'matrix index' to get to a 'python index'.

Comment: So I am dealing with 2 types of index. The index for the matrix and the index for the list. Matrix index starts at 1, the List index starts at 0. Matrix index can only be positive, List index can be positive or negative. Matrix index 1 is equivalent to List index 0! The [index-1] I asked about is the matrix index and not the list index. Does the above explanation make sense?

Comment: Yes that is perfect!